# How to safely use possibly unsafe data with Query::select()?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, select, cakephp-3.0

First all, sorry about my english!
I'm trying do a dynamic select in CakePHP when i need change the statements of search. I know can use a variable to do that, but i think about SQL injection. It has other way to do this ?

Example:

```
$var = "quantidade";//$var can be other values.
$query->find('')->select('quantidade' => $var);
```

Comment: Should be find('all') or any other ..

Comment: cakephp can handle basic  SQL injection , Beauty of MVC..

Comment: @Confused There is no SQL injection prevention in `Query::select()`!!

Comment: @ndm I was not specific about select() .  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#sql-injection-prevention

Comment: @Confused But the question is about the `select()` method, so people that read your statement might get the wrong impression about how it works, hence my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike in other places like `Query::where()` when using the `key => value` syntax, there are no SQL injection prevention mechanisms in `Query::select()`, values passed to this method are being inserted into the query as is (they might get quoted, but not escaped), so you have to take care of securing this yourself.

I'd suggest to use a whitelist, either a hardcoded one:

```
$allowedFields = [
    'field_a',
    'field_b'
];

if (in_array($var, $allowedFields, true)) {
    $query = $Table
        ->find()
        ->select([
            'alias' => $var
        ]);
}
```

or one retrieved from the tables schema in case you want to allow all fields, but **be careful**, only do this if it's definitely safe to expose all possible columns to the user!

```
$allowedFields = $Table->getSchema()->columns(); // use schema() in CakePHP < 3.4
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > SQL Injection Prevention](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#sql-injection-prevention)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Schema System](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::getSchema()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_getSchema)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::schema()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_schema)**